# Issue saving TIFF file with IStreamWriter under ServiceStack

Tags: streaming, servicestack

I am using the ServiceStack framework to stream a TIFF file.
When I use an IStreamWriter interface, it saves only the first page using an image object.
I am looking for an example of how to use the same stream for a multipage TIFF file.

Comment: Please share part of your code to reproduce the bevavior.

Comment: I got the solution , we need to  use copyTo method of stream

Comment: public void WriteTo(Stream responseStream)
        {
            if (_responseStream == null)
                return;

            _responseStream.CopyTo(responseStream);
            responseStream.Flush();
            //dispose
            responseStream.Dispose();
        }